# Switch activities from one package to another?

Tags: android, android-intent, package, android-activity

My main package is called `com.android.cats`, and I created a another package (in the same app) named `com.android.dog`. In package `com.android.cats` I created an Activity called `Meow.java`, and in package `com.android.dog` I created an Activity called `Ruff.java`. My question is: how can I switch the activity from `Meow.java` to `Ruff.java`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare your activities in `AndroidManifest.xml` similar to the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    package="com.android"
...
>
...
<activity android:name=".cats.Meow" />
<activity android:name=".dogs.Ruff" />
...
```

Then in your application code, launch your intents as you usually would, of course using the full package name instead (i.e. `com.android.dogs.Ruff`)

Comment: Is this I suppose to launch intent startActivity(new Intent(Meow.this, com.android.dogs.Ruff.class));?

Comment: @Leon I take that back, you may not have to use the full com.android.dogs.Ruff.class if you've imported it correctly. But yeah, that's the general idea.

Comment: Should the activities in ANidroidManifest.xml looks like this: <activity android:name="(dot)com.android.cats.Meow" /> with dot? Because I tried what you told me and it game me an error, it says "There is a problem parsing the package"

Comment: @Leon If you set your package name to the base name (i.e. **com.android**), then **.cats.Meow** and **.dogs.Ruff** _should_ work. See my edited post.

Comment: So my intent should be look like this  startActivity(new Intent(Meow.this, Ruff.class))? instead of com.android.dogs.Ruff.class?

Comment: @Leon That _should_ work. Did you run into any issues with it?

Comment: Hold on, my eclipse is too slow